# Stomp client doesn't receive message on user destination?

Tags: java, spring, spring-websocket, stomp

I'm having the problem that a stomp message send to a user-destination is not received by the client. Let me explain:

In WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer:

```
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
config.enableSimpleBroker("/secured/topic", "/secured/user/queue");
config.setUserDestinationPrefix("/secured/user");
..
```

On my stompjs client (logged in as "admin"):

```
stompClient.subscribe('/secured/user/queue/notifications'
                        , function (output) {
                            console.log(output);
                        });
```

In the log:

```
Processing SUBSCRIBE /secured/user/queue/notifications id=sub-0 session=d74f49b3-bb63-580f-b862-81647cc712b3
```

And java code to send the message:

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(
      "admin", "/secured/user/queue/notifications", out);
```

Which results in log:

```
Processing MESSAGE destination=/secured/user/queue/notifications-userd74f49b3-bb63-580f-b862-81647cc712b3 session=null payload={"from":"server","text":"hello","recipient":"admin","time":"13:29:10"}
      -
```

But no message is printed in the console log.

As you can see the sessionid is the same in the subscribe and send step. But i don't understand why the client doesn't get the message. Note that message without user destination are working correctly.

Can anybody offer me a helping hand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working trying many variations, I'm only not sure why it working, but i don't complain. What i did:

In configureMessageBroker (WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer) (this really confuses me goes against all samples i read):

```
config.enableSimpleBroker("/secured/topic", "/secured/queue", "/secured/user");
```

convertAndSendToUser (the "/secured/user" + username is added by convertAndSendToUser):

```
simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(   "admin", "/queue/notifications", out);
```

and my subscribe on the client (not really happy about adding username here..):

```
stompClient.subscribe("/secured/user/"+userName+"/queue/notifications"
                        , function (output) {
```

But it works ;-)

[edit]
Trace logging makes it easier to understand what is going on:

```
  <Logger name="org.springframework.messaging" level="trace" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Logger>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should create your own user principal model class to determine it has correct username like this.

```
public class StompPrincipal implements Principal {
    String name;
    String userid;
  
    public StompPrincipal(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Also you should create a `DefaultHandshakeHandler` implementation to create user with the name you choose.

```
public class CustomHandshakeHandler extends DefaultHandshakeHandler {
    // Custom class for storing principal
    @Override
    protected Principal determineUser(ServerHttpRequest request,
                                      WebSocketHandler wsHandler,
                                      Map<String, Object> attributes) {

        // Generate principal with UUID as name
        return new StompPrincipal(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    }
}
```

And finally add this `CustomHandshakeHandler` class to `setHandshakeHandler` method as below

```
 @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {

        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*")
                .setHandshakeHandler(new CustomHandshakeHandler());
    }
```

Comment: Cheers, that would be indeed quite handy if it would be anonymous users, but I'm using spring security to do all the login stuff, which is working correctly. You can also look at the log messages that the correct session id (d74f49b3-bb63-580f-b862-81647cc712b3) for user "admin" is found, it matches the subscribe request from this user.

Comment: I think you can set constructor parameter for `StompPrincipal` as `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()` in `determineUser` function. waiting if it is working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but as i noted in my previous comment i don't think that the Principal class is the problem, just take a peek at the session id's, "admin" resolves to the right "sessionid". The only problem here is that i don't receive it on the client.

Comment: Stomp doesn't know 'admin' user.So if you want to send the message to this user, You need to know it's 'sessionid' .One of the way stomp know it is creating custom principal as the code above.The other way is opening connection with header parameters including username info.After that you can store username and session id in the list.And send the message for admin with its sessionid from the list.

Comment: Stomp is an extra layer above the websocket, if i understand correctly if you do spring security + stomp the principal is known. I did a quick test adding "log.debug(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName())" to a method with @MessageMapping and it did print the logged in user.